# Will my app work on Android 5.0?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have these lines in my app's Gradle Settings:

```
compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 25
    }

    ...bla bla bla...

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.0.0'
```

So will my app launch and work on Android 5.0?

Comment: @YuriiKyrylchuk oh, thank you very much. Please place your comment as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your app has minSdkVersion 21, which is equals to Lolipop 5.0, so yes, it will

Answer (score 0):

Most likely it won't check the page [Platform Codenames, Versions, API Levels, and NDK Releases](https://source.android.com/source/build-numbers.html) You are using the platform version 7.1 to compile. Any method call that does not exist in API21 but does on API25 will cause an error. If you are going to develop for an older versions you will be better off compiling with the older version. Also check the  [support library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/index.html) if you are going to implement some new feature but want it to be backward compatible.